# Get a list of all gitignore files in my current branch, unrelated to their tracking or modification state

Tags: git, gitignore

I asked this question already again, but it was closed prematurely, since the given link did not answer my question as explained. I have a Git repo and would like to get a list of files, which are ignored by Git in my current branch, and those which are not, unrelated to if they are tracked, or not, or what their state is.

I found `git-check-ignore`, but my repository has a few thousand files, and checking it on a per file basis takes simply too long to spawn a process for each file.

```
git check-ignore /file/to/foo
```

Does Git have another command that allows me to get a list of files which are ignored by git?

Comment: Does `git-status` work for you?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately not. It seems no matter what combination or flag I use, the results vary and if a file is already tracked or not tracked, modified, or not modified. But I never get a simple or complete list of files I am looking for

Comment: ok, makes sense, good you opened again. some people are simply to quick with their close votes. ignore them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the command you're looking for is `git ls-files -ioc --exclude-standard`.  That command will list files using the standard exclude paths that are either tracked (in the index) or untracked.

Even if that's not the exact invocation that you're looking for, `git ls-files` is the tool which is most likely to give you an efficient answer.  It also has the `-z` option which is useful for odd filenames and scripting use.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for! :-)